# Simple way to run SQL queries in IBM Data Studio

Tags: sql, ibm-data-studio

How can I run a simple query like:

```
select current timestamp from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

In the old "Command Center" if was simply able to run such a command without creating a script/project, using a query builder etc.. However the old command center was replaced with the new Data Studio during an update.

I'm trying to reproduce an error that doesn't pop up when using my usual Aqua Data studio. However running the procedure with JDBC and/or the Data Studio throws an exception.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) Open "Database Administration" perspective in data studio

2) To launch the SQL editor, go to Administration Explorer on the left panel and click New > New SQL Script  (Refer screenshot below)

[image: Screenshot To Open Sql editor]

This way you can run your normal sql queries without creating a script/project, etc. Please refer to IBM official site [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1201migctrlctrdatastudio/) for more details.